# Invalid memory access

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I wrote a DLL that has to be used in Java:

```
public interface MyInterface extends Library {
   public void GetDllVersion(char[] buffer, int bufferLen);
   ...
}

MyInterface instance=(MyInterface) Native.loadLibrary(basename,MyInterface.class);
char[] buffer=new char[20];
instance.GetDllVersion(buffer,buffer.length);
```

The corresponding C Code is

```
void __declspec(dllexport) GetDllVersion(char *buffer,int bufferLen) {
  ...
}
```

I also turned `jna.debug_load` on to see some output. The lib is loaded as expected, but the call to `GetDllVersion`fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
   at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:367)
   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
   at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetDllVersion(Unknown Source)
   at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Dependency Walker shows that the DLL exports this function.

How to find out what exactly is wrong with the function call?

Comment: maybe GetDllVersion expects the buffer to be longer than 20 bytes?

Comment: For testing purposes I commented out everything inside the GetDllVersion method body. So practically this function does nothing

Comment: @k_wave - So you have no way to use the debugger to debug the DLL function?  I'm pretty sure the DLL can be debugged using the debugger, and you need to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to a mismatch in the size of the **Java 16 bit char** vs the size of the **C 8 bit char**.  One solution is to pass data as a byte[].

```
public void GetDllVersion(byte[] buffer, int bufferLen);
```

and

```
__declspec(dllexport) void GetDllVersion(byte *buffer,int bufferLen) {
```

Another solution is to use wide char on the native side.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void GetDllVersion(wchar_t *buffer,int bufferLen) {
```